# load and read differents Json file using MathRandom()

Tags: javascript, html, json

how can I read and load differents Json files using JavaScript?
example: Json1, Json2, Json3, Json4
some loop thats load on different Json every 30s

was trying and looking, how to make it but nothing works for me, any idea?

wants to include in this code

```
 function loadpoints() {   function getData(){

     $.getJSON('pointer.json', function(pointer) {

       var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

       $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {
         //where its my data working 

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
           title: ponto.activity,
           icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
           map: map
         });

         console.log("created marker " + marker.position)

       });

       setTimeout (getData, 3000);   });
        }

     getData();

   }
```

Comment: Why do you put the body of getData function inside another function?

Comment: was triyng to makes the function reload works. but alredy change

Comment: just add the new code bellow! Im stuck how his gonna read the files like 
pointer and changed to pointer1(example) and display that

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mojtaba 
function genereteRamdon (min, max){
    var arr=[];
    while (arr.length<4){
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+!))+min;
      found=false;

      for (var i=0, i<arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[1] = randomNumber){found=true; break}
      }
      return arr;
    }

  }



  $.getJSON('pointer.json', function(pointer) {

    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
        title: ponto.activity,
        icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
        map: map
      });

      console.log("created marker " + marker.position)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not much clear what are you trying to get.

I guess you want this:

```
function getData(){

    $.getJSON('pointer.json', function(pointer) {

        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        $.each(pointer, function(index, ponto) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(ponto.lat, ponto.lon),
            title: ponto.activity,
            icon: ponto.activity + '.png',
            map: map
            });

            console.log("created marker " + marker.position)

        });

}

getData();
setInterval(getData, 30000);
```

Comment: I've 3 externals files
1.json, 2.json and 3.json

inside my javascript i need/trying something with
math.random to read,
length to calculte size of my array 
and something to call my JSON file like $.get.

can you help me pls?
to do a random read (math.random) and then display 

i believe i need something with

Answer (score 0):

solution :)

this piece of code was looking for

```
var min=1; var max = 4 // max number off json 

   var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min; var jsonfile =
   "pointer" + random.toString()+".json" //display one of the files


   $.getJSON(jsonfile, function(pointer)
```